# Tailwind -- Make columns scroll independently

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind to create a two column child layout within a general application layout. Both columns can theoretically overflow the height of the parent div, so I would like them to scroll. However, so far, I can only get them to scroll together. I want to make them scroll independently, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

Parent Component:

```js
<div className="flex flex-col h-screen md:pl-64">
  <div className="sticky top-0 z-10 flex h-16 flex-shrink-0 bg-neutral-600 bg-opacity-50 backdrop-blur-3xl">
    ...
  </div>

  <main className="overflow-auto">
    <Routes>
      <Route path="desk" element={<Desk />} />
      <Route path="messaging/*" element={<Messaging />} />
    </Routes>
  </main>
</div>
```

Messaging Component:

```js
<div className="flex">
  <div className="w-1/3">
    <ThreadsPanel header={false} full={true} rounded={false} />
  </div>
  <div className="w-2/3">
    <Routes>
      <Route path=":thread" element={<ThreadMessages />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Move `overflow-auto` lower into each component's root as opposed to on `main`

Comment: @ksav I've tried adding it at basically every level in every combination. I only have it on the main component because that got me closest to what I wanted.

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using `overflow-y: scroll;` at your Messaging Component div

for example try :

```
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll;" className="flex">
  <div className="w-1/3">
    <ThreadsPanel header={false} full={true} rounded={false} />
  </div>
  <div className="w-2/3">
    <Routes>
      <Route path=":thread" element={<ThreadMessages />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This causes everything to scroll including the background

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `html`, `body` and any further child elements have `height:100%` or the `h-full` class.

Note that `main` has the `h-full` class.

Then apply the `overflow-auto` class to each scrollable section.

```js
const insertElements = (parent, num = 60) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    const newLi = document.createElement("li");
    newLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Item number ${i+1}`));
    parent.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', newLi);
  }
}


document.querySelectorAll('.main > .list').forEach((col) => {
  insertElements(col);
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<main class="main flex h-full">
  <ul class="list flex-1 overflow-auto"></ul>
  <ul class="list flex-1 overflow-auto"></ul>
</main>
```